# Discrete Cumulative Probability Distribution

Tags: probability-distributions

Given F(x) = P(X <= x) for a discrete random variable
which of the following is generally true

$P(a <= X <= b) = F(b) - F(a), 
P(a < X < b) = F(b) - F(a),
P(a <= X < b) = F(b) - F(a),
P(a < X <= b) = F(b) - F(a)$

Comment: Please see https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since the variable is discrete, it is generally correct the following:
$$P(a<x\leq b)=F(b)-F(a)$$